# Is API related code will be present in default magento pack?

Tags: api, soap

in the default magento pack , means including app to var.

Is all the code related to APIs will be present ?

Means is there any web services/API related code will be there in default pack.

for example , for getting shipping methods as we are using this API : **shoppingCartShippingList()** , to support these API's is there any code will be present in default pack ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the API related functionalities are present in default pack. However to or not to enable those Magento API can be configured from Magento Backend. Magento API also has some of the limitation. I have been lately working myself with Magento API and it has limitation that it does not give any information in group attributes. There could be other limitation as well but I haven't been able to explore them yet.

The default pack comes with both Versions1.x and Version2 of Magento API, XML-RPC based and SOAP based. You can choose one that you are comfortable with. I have successfully utilized the XML-RPC based calls to consume the Magento 1.x API.

visit https://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/salesOrder.html to see the example sales order.